# how to create an array of NSDictionarys

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary

I would like to fetch the information I have stored into one of my core data objects and store this data into an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, so that I can send this array of to one of my views and display the data in a tableview.

However I am not quite sure how to get the `NSDictionary` into the `NSArray`, this is my fetch request as it stands, hopefully someone can give me a hand putting the `NSDictionary` into a `NSArray`.. Im not sure how to do this because of how I am looping though the Core Data Object.

```
// Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error; 

        NSMutableDictionary *tempManufacturerDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (Manuf *manuf in fetchedObjects) {
            [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.hasMod forKey:@"HASMOD"];
            [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.isLocked forKey:@"ISLOCKED"];
            [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.isReg forKey:@"ISREG"];
            [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.main forKey:@"MAIN"];

            // How do I put the Dictionary above into an array?
        }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add your dictionary to an object of type `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate an `NSMutableArray` before entering the loop, and declare a new `NSMutableDictionary` during every iteration, like so:

```
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (Manuf *manuf in fetchedObjects) {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempManufacturerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.hasMod forKey:@"HASMOD"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.isLocked forKey:@"ISLOCKED"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.isReg forKey:@"ISREG"];
        [tempManufacturerDictionary setObject:manuf.main forKey:@"MAIN"];

        [array addObject:tempManufacturerDictionary];
    }
```

You could also set the `resultType` of your fetch request to be `NSDictionaryResultType` and get an array of dictionaries from the fetch request in the first place.

Comment: @HurkNburkS hopefully it will help you out!

Comment: yeah thanks for that going to check it out now :P I would imagine it might speed things up abit. As from the testing I have been doing with creating this dictionary takes a second or three with the amount of stat i have in it..

Comment: bit lost on how to use this resultType.. the thing is I think maybe I have to stick with the way I am doing it because I have created a Core Data Object class which has all of the variables declared in it.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Hm, you might have to set the property descriptions as well... been a long time since I messed with this!

Comment: @HurkNburkS but yes it's dead simple to use Logan's answer - just instantiate an `NSMutableArray` andthen every iteration of the loop call `addObject:` on it.

Comment: I have added this to the bottom of my for loop **[manufacturerDictionaryArray addObject:tempMainDictionary];** but for some odd reason when I log the array it shows that every single entry is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17271/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-hurknburks)

Answer (score 2):

Just like you would any other object, using `addObject`.

You need to be using an `NSMutableArray` though, not a normal `NSArray` to be able to add elements. You can convert a mutable array into a normal array later if you strictly need an immutable version.

Comment: but being that I am in a look do I need to define some sort of count? when it uns thorough each time ?